# $\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} (x-A)^{\gamma-1} \mathrm{d} x$, where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \ge 1$, and $A < 0$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is there an analytical expression for this integral?

$$\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} (x-A)^{\gamma-1} \mathrm{d} x$$

where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \ge 1$, and $A < 0$.

P.S.: By analytical expression, I mean, pragmatically, an expression in terms of functions usually found in numeric computation libraries.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/793884/10063

Comment: The particular case with $\gamma=1$ coincides with the Beta function. So no.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why not? The Beta function is an "analytical expression" for me.

Comment: Mostly a matter of convention.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Agree. Pragmatically what I mean is an expression in terms of functions usually found in numeric computation libraries.

Comment: That's an excellent criterion, you could have stated it upfront. Then of course, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral can be expressed on a closed form, thanks to the Hypergeometric2F1 function :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What is amazing is that the antiderivative can be analytically expressed on the basis of Appell hypergeometric functions of two variables. For the integral, similar to what O.L. answered, I (a CAS did it !) obtained
$$\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1} (x-A)^{\gamma-1} \mathrm{d} x= (-A)^{\gamma-1}\Gamma (\alpha) \Gamma (\beta) \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(\alpha,1-\gamma;\alpha+\beta;\frac{1}{A}\right)$$ where appears the  regularized hypergeometric function which can be expressed using, from definition, the  classical hypergeometric function

Comment: Hi Claude ! I Our answers are consistent according to the relationship between standard- and regularized- hypergeometric2F1.

Comment: @JJacquelin. Yes, indeed (by definition of the regularized function).  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your expression essentially coincides with the [Euler's integral representation of the Gauss hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type):
$$_2F_1(a,b;c;t)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}\int_0^1\frac{x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}}{(1-tx)^a}dx.$$